# Convert Arabic string to an array of bytes

Tags: vb.net, arrays, arabic

I have a function which converts string to an array of bytes. If the string is written in English, the function works fine. But if the input string is Arabic, the function doesn't return, and I get this error:

> Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte

```
Friend Function StringtoByteArray(ByRef value As String) As Byte()
    Dim temp() As Byte
    ReDim temp(Len(value) - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Len(value) - 1 Step 1
        temp(i) = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToChar(Mid(value, i + 1, 1)))
    Next
    StringtoByteArray = temp
 End Function
```

What should I change to convert Arabic characters to byte?

I am using VB.NET.

Comment: problem solved
    Friend Function StringtoByteArray(ByRef value As String) As Byte()
        Try
            Dim rawBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value)
            StringtoByteArray = rawBytes
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

      End Function

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your function for that, this should work:

```
Dim b As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value)
```